# VC++ Access violation reading from private member value types (bool)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, access-violation

I am getting this weird error where I get an access violation from reading private class-level values (no pointers).

```
HRESULT WindowedSinkRenderer::Initialize(IMLTeeSink3 *sink)
{
    std::cout << "Test\n";

    // exception throw here
    std::cout << "Test" << _isInitialized << "\n";

    std::cout << "Test\n";

    return S_OK;
}
```

Here is my header

```
class WindowedSinkRenderer
{
public:
    WindowedSinkRenderer();
    ~WindowedSinkRenderer();

    HRESULT Initialize(IMLTeeSink3 *sink);
    HRESULT Deinitialize();
    HRESULT SetRenderOwner(HWND handle);
    HRESULT SetRenderDimensions(int width, int height, bool fillVideo);
    HRESULT GetCurrentImage(BITMAPINFOHEADER* bitmapHeader, BYTE** data, DWORD* size, bool* bufferHasInfoHeader);

private:

    DWORD _remoteGraphRegister;
    SmartPtr<IGraphBuilder> _graphBuilder;
    SmartPtr<IFilterGraph2> _filterGraph;
    SmartPtr<IMediaControl> _mediaControl;
    WindowedVideoRenderer* _videoRenderer;

    bool _isInitialized;

};
```

And here is my constructor where it event initializes the bool to false.

```
WindowedSinkRenderer::WindowedSinkRenderer() : _isInitialized(false)
{

}
```

What gives? Why the error?

```
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDE1.
```

Comment: Please show code where you call `WindowedSinkRenderer::Initialize()`

Comment: The pattern `0xcdcdcdcd` is the typical pattern of uninitialized memory (see e.g. [this page for a reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260966%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)). `0xCDCDCDE1` seems like an offset from an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It was an invalid pointer to a WindowedSinkRenderer. It threw me off because I could still execute code in the method, provided that I treat the method as a static method (not accessing instance members).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are calling Initialize with an invalid pointer to a WindowedSinkRenderer object.

Comment: That was it! I was thrown off because I could in-fact debug INTO the method.

So, using methods on an invalid pointer is valid if you treat this "instance" method as "static"? Not recommending that, just interesting to know.

Comment: The invalid pointer is not actually used until you attempt to access a member variable.